# Second Order ODE using Neural Network

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, differential-equations

I'm studying numerical methods for ODEs and i'm using machine learning for it.
I'm trying to implement an 2nd order ODE in the code that i'm using to solve a 1st order ODE.
The ODE that i want to solve is: y'' = -10y, where y(0) = 0 and y'(0) = 1.
My question is: I know i need to break the 2nd order ODE in two 1st order ODE, but, how do i do that? I need to change f(x) (Check code bellow)?
How do i implement the 2nd order in the loss function?
The GradientTape need to be changed?

I know it is very basic stuffs, but im really new at machine learning and i'm trying to learn it.

Thanks!

Leo

*Here is the code i'm using at moment for 1st order ODE.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(123)
tf.random.set_seed(123)

#Condições Iniciais
f0 = 1

# Número Infinitesimal
inf_s = np.sqrt(np.finfo(np.float32).eps)

# Parâmetros
learning_rate = 0.01
training_steps = 5000
batch_size = 100
display_step = training_steps/10

# Parâmetros da Rede
n_input = 1 
n_hidden_1 = 32
n_hidden_2 = 32
n_output = 1

weights = {
    'h1': tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([n_input, n_hidden_1])),
    'h2': tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([n_hidden_1, n_hidden_2])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([n_hidden_2, n_output]))
}
biases = {
    'b1': tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([n_hidden_1])),
    'b2': tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([n_hidden_2])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([n_output]))
}

# Otimizador gradiente descendente
optimizer = tf.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate)

# Criando Modelo
def multilayer_perceptron(x):
    x = np.array([[[x]]], dtype= 'float32')
    # Camada escondida 1 com 32 neuronios
    layer_1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, weights['h1']), biases['b1'])
    layer_1 = tf.nn.sigmoid(layer_1) #Relu não funciona melhor?
    # Camada escondida 2 com 32 neuronios
    layer_2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1, weights['h2']), biases['b2'])
    layer_2 = tf.nn.sigmoid(layer_2) #Relu
    # Camada de saida
    output = tf.matmul(layer_2, weights['out']) + biases['out']
    return output

# Aproximador universal
def g(x):
    return x * multilayer_perceptron(x) + f0
# EDO
def f(x):
    return x-x**2 

# Função Custo
def custom_loss():
    summation = []
    for x in np.linspace(0,1,10):
        dNN = (g(x+inf_s)-g(x))/inf_s
        summation.append((dNN - f(x))**2)
    return tf.reduce_sum(tf.abs(summation))

def train_step():
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        loss = custom_loss()
    trainable_variables = list(weights.values()) + list(biases.values())
    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, trainable_variables)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, trainable_variables))

for i in range(training_steps):
    train_step()
    if i % display_step == 0:
        print("loss: %f " % (custom_loss()))

from matplotlib.pyplot import figure

figure(figsize=(10,10))

# True Solution 
def true_solution(x):
    return  (1/6)*(-2*x**3 + 3*x**2 + 6)

X = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
result = []
for i in X:
  result.append(g(i).numpy()[0][0][0])

S = true_solution(X)
  
plt.plot(X, S, label="Original Function")
plt.plot(X, result, label="Neural Net Approximation")
plt.legend(loc=2, prop={'size': 20})
plt.show()
```

I'm expecting some answers to my question. It can be books, articles, example of codes or just some thoughts on my question. I tried to implemente the 2nd order in my code but i stuck in the loss function since it need to be different that in the original code. The function f(x) and g(x) are also a big question for me.

Comment: I'm not sure that is clear what's your question... what's the actual problem with the code you posted?

Comment: Agree with @AlbertoSinigaglia, what exactly would you like to know?

Comment: I want to solve an 2nd order ODE using NN. The code i posted i was asking for help for changes. I'm trying to implement the 2nd order ODE. The code i posted i was solving it for 1st order ODE.